# IE : HTML select with huge options taking lot of time in loading

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html-select

My requirement is to load a HTML drop down dynamically.

`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addSelectBox()
        {
            var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
            var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");
            for (var i=0;i < 6000;i++)
            {
                var option = new Option ("Option --- " + i, "Value" + i);
                selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
            }
            parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
        <input type="button" onclick="addSelectBox()" 
         name="clickme" value="Add Select Box" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

In above code, On clicking of the button, I'm creating dropdown with the options and adding it to the div.

This takes very less time (2-5 secs) in Firefox and Chrome. But when I run it in Internet Explorer (11) it's taking more than 20 seconds. 
And while loading, the page gets hanged it blocks the other operations also.

Please find jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/16264/)

Is there any other way, so it can be fast in IE. 
Or 
Is it possible to load it in background and show loading message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead. Much faster

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7wr9cchw/)

```
function addSelectBox(){
   var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
   var selectElement = '<select>';
   for (var i=0;i < 6000;i++) {
     selectElement+= '<option value="'+i+'">---- ' + i+'</option>';
   }
   selectElement += '</select>';
   parentDiv.innerHTML+=selectElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this by building up the text and then setting the `innerHTML`, it takes almost no time at all.  [Fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly3uLc8o/1/)

```
var selectText = "<select>";
for (var i = 0; i < 6000; ++i)
    selectText += "<option value=" + i + ">Option " + i;
selectText += "</select>"
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = selectText;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is building the huge option list and then appending that takes the time. **Adding the element to parent div first and then add options to it works** :

```
function addSelectBox(){
   var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("main");
   var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");

   parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement); // ADD FIRST

   for (var i=0;i < 6000;i++)
   {
        var option = new Option ("Option ---- " + i, "Value" + i);

        selectElement.appendChild(option); // ADD OPTIONS TO IT
    }

}
```